# Java circular Generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm having a problem understanding Java generics and I've simplified to this example

```
class A<T extends B> {

    public void fun(T t) {

    }
}

class B {
    A a;

    public void event() {
        a.fun(this);
    }

}
```

The problem is that this generates a warning because A is defined inside B but A is already using it as a generic type.

My first instinct would be that my design is wrong, but in this case I can't change it. A is like a collection and B is like a node in the collection that users are supposed to override. Certain events can happen in B that require reporting back to the parent A.

But since A is defined generically with B, how do I avoid the compile warning inside B.event()

Thanks

Comment: The only warning I can see is the use of A as a raw type. If that isn't the warning you're referring to, please be more specific, and tell us which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Code**

```
public class A<T extends B> {
    public void fun(T t) {
    }
}

public class B {
    A<B> a;

    public void event() {
        a.fun(this);
    }
}
```

The warning is vanquished.

**Reason**

Variables of type `A` should be declared using a *specific* class type, as suggested by the *generic* class signature (`A<T extends B>`).

**Resolution**

While this resolves the compiler warning, the underlying problem remains. Laurence provides an excellent explanation and solution to the core issue.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that you're using a raw type on this line:

```
A a;
```

You need to specify a type for A's type parameter (T).

You could do something like this:

```
A<B> a;
```

but then A might as well not be generic at all, if I'm understanding your statement of the problem. You probably want to do something like this:

```
class A<T> {
  public void fun(T t) {

  }
}

class B<T extends B<T>> {
  A<B<T>> a;
  public void event() {
    a.fun(this);
  }
}
```

or even this:

```
class A<T extends B<? extends T>> {
  public void fun(T t) {

  }
}

class B<T extends B<T>> {
  A<? super B<T>> a;
  public void event() {
    a.fun(this);
  }
}
```

There are a couple of variations in-between these that are possibly useful as well. The latter example is the most generic (but obviously, also the most complicated).

The `class A<T extends B<? extends T>>` is ensuring that the type parameter to A is a B. Since B is itself generic, and has that cyclic type parameter, you end up needing to say `B<? extends T>` (simply saying T won't work here).

The `class B<T extends B<T>>` is as close as you can get to emulating a "self type" in Java. This lets B talk about the (almost) concrete subtype of itself. When subclassing B you'd say something like "`class C extends <B<C>>`". This is useful because now the type of `C.a` is actually `A<? super B<C>>`.

The `? super` bit in the latter example is only useful if you plan on connecting a B with an `A` that isn't for exactly the same type of `B`. Thinking in concrete terms, suppose you had an `A<Shape>` and a `Circle` (which extends `Shape` which extends `B`). The  super-wildcard lets you use them together. Without it you'd need an `A<Circle>` rather than an `A<Shape>` for your `Circle`.